# Counting the characters in C

Tags: c

Ive just started with programming and im using a Codeblocks compiler. With this code

```
long x = 0;

while(getchar() != EOF){
    ++x;
}

printf("%ld\n", x);
```

I am trying to count the characters of the input, but everytime I run the program it does not print anything at all.

However, this version

```
long x = 0;

while(getchar() != EOF){
    ++x;

printf("%ld\n", x);
}
```

prints the number of characters succesfully, but on the other hand it counts every single character(it shows me 1,2,3,4 instead of just 4).

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: When you run the program, does the console appear as a separate window that then closes when you send EOF?

Comment: because you are using a while loop and while loops keep doing the printing until the end of the sentence you are counting

Comment: How are you sending `EOF`?

Comment: Replace `EOF` with `'\n'`. When you enter some characters and press enter it should print the right number.

Comment: EOF is end-of-file. Change it by end-of-line, that is '\n'.

Comment: What is the difference in the version shown? (am I that blind?)

Comment: (disregard - I am blind..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are using EOF in while loop which means "end of file", it is basically used when you want to read from a text file. 
Now I explain you what is happening in your both codes than I will tell you how to solve it.

First code:

```
long x = 0;

while(getchar() != EOF){
   ++x;
}

printf("%ld\n", x);
```

Here you are taking input from the keyboard as long as EOF doesn't occur and once EOF occurs than loop will break and printf() will be executed but in this case EOF will not occur and as a result nothing will be printed.

Second code:

```
long x = 0;

while(getchar() != EOF){
   ++x;
printf("%ld\n", x);
}
```

The loop will continue as long as EOF doesn't occur and will keep on printing the value of x because printf() is present inside the while loop, so printf() will be executed as many times as the loop iterates.

Solution: 
Replace EOF with something else, any other character eg a space like this

```
long x = 0;

while(getchar() != ' '){
    ++x;
}

printf("%ld\n", x);
```

Comment: Oh I see, I couldnt figure out that it wasnt end of file yet, thanks

Answer (score 4):

How are you running the program, and how are you supplying the input? My assumptions are the following:

1. You are running the program via a terminal
2. The program wont actually end until you hit ctrl + c, and you expect
3. You are supplying input by typing characters via the keyboard

If these are true, you will need to type the EOF character (ctrl + z on Windows, ctrl + d on Mac, probably the same on other unix). Alternatively, you can feed the program a file by using the `< file.ext` syntax. For example: `./a.out < input.txt`

Comment: It is worth noting that on Windows, you must type Ctrl-Z at the beginning of a line followed by pressing Enter/Return, or by pressing Ctrl-Z repeatedly (2-3 times?) to discard all input on the line and send EOF instead. On other systems where it is Ctrl-D, you need only press it to end the program if you have not entered anything else; pressing Enter/Return is unnecessary. Otherwise, you must press Ctrl-D repeatedly (2-3 times probably) to send EOF.